# Changing the Class of Multiple Elements OnResize using JQuery

Tags: jquery, class, onresize

Ok I am entirely new to jQuery, and it looks like I should have been getting into this all much sooner coz it certainly offers a whole bunch of options that are truly awesome. Now.. I want to do the following:

When a user resizes a page, I want to be able to set the ClassName for a variety of elements at the same time. So if the width is between range A and B, set class 1, between B and C, set class 2, and so on. So far I have this:

```
<Script>
var sClass;
sClass = 'v11';
$(window).resize(function(){
CW = document.body.clientWidth;

if (CW >= 1 && CW <= 460) {sClass = 'v10';}
if (CW >= 461 && CW <= 770) {sClass = 'v11';}
if (CW >= 771 && CW <= 1100) {sClass = 'v12';}
document.getElementById('ZVal').value=CW;
document.getElementById('CVal').value=sClass;
    $(".zahbib").attr('class',sClass);
});
</script>

<Body LeftMargin='0' TopMargin='0' MarginHeight='0' MarginWidth='0'>

<InPut Type='Text' ID='ZVal'>
<InPut Type='Text' ID='CVal'>


<Table Width='100%' CellSpacing='0' CellPadding='0' Border='0'>
<Tr>
<Td class='zahbib' Width='40%'>Name:</Td>
<Td Width='60%'><InPut class='zahbib' Type='Text' Style='Width:100%'></Td>
</Tr>
<Tr>
<Td class='zahbib' Width='40%'>Email:</Td>
<Td Width='60%'><InPut class='zahbib' Type='Text' Style='Width:100%'></Td>
</Tr>
<Tr>
<Td class='zahbib' Width='40%'>Phone:</Td>
<Td Width='60%'><Select class='zahbib' Style='Width:100%'></Select></Td>
</Tr>
</Table>

</Body>
```

I have gotten most of this (especially the jquery stuff) from other Stack Overflow posts, but changing the class only happens ONCE and then it does not change again depending on the width. It just seems to complete the task 1 time, and not for the text fields either, I think.

So what am I doing wrong? The sClass value works OK, updates the debug text field, as does the width readout. I know it can return slightly different values depending on browser but that's OK, it will not need it to be super-precise.

Many thanks and I am hoping to start getting into this jQuery thing more thoroughly :)
W

The CSS I am now using is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 460px){
zeb{font-size:12px}
zah{font-size:12px}
input.text{font-size:12px}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 461px) and (max-width: 770px){
zeb{font-size:16px}
zah{font-size:16px}
input.text{font-size:12px}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 771px) and (max-width: 1920px){
zeb{font-size:22px}
zah{font-size:22px}
input{font-size:12px}
}
```

zeb and zah are where you normally put div. I just would prefer not to use DIV because there may be some divs that I do not want affected. This way, I can simply make my own tags at will, and this works perfectly fine. (so instead of `<div></div>`  I type `<zah>` and `</zah>`) They work. It's just the input fields that wont budge. Thank You :)

Ok this is the table:

```
<Table Width='100%' CellSpacing='0' CellPadding='0' Border='0'>
<Tr>
<Td Class='v11' Width='40%'><zeb>Name:</zeb></Td>
<Td Width='60%'><input Type='Text' Style='Width:100%'></Td>
</Tr>
<Tr>
<Td Class='v11' Width='40%'><zah>Email:</zah></Td>
<Td Width='60%'><input Type='Text' Style='Width:100%'></Td>
</Tr>
<Tr>
<Td Class='v11' Width='40%'><zah>Phone:</zah></Td>
<Td Width='60%'><Select Style='Width:100%'></Select></Td>
</Tr>
</Table>
```

And as I said, the font size is adjusted fine on the zeb and zah :) Just the input fields won't change as I resize the window. The zeb's and zah's do :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel what you are trying to do can be accomplished much more easily using media queries. You can encase your rules in media queries that will ensure the style rules applied depend on the width of the viewport.

So for example, to set the style for all divs when the screen is between 1 and 460 pixels wide, you could use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 460px){
  div {
      color: red;
  }
}
```

Additionally we could say we want the color to be green when the width is between 461 and 770 pixels:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 460px){
  div {
      color: red;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 461px) and (max-width: 770px){
  div {
      color: green;
  }
}
```

You are using non standard HTML elements. Try using `span` elements and using IDs to isolate them in CSS:

```
<Table Width="100%" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" Border="0">
   <Tr>
      <Td Class="v11" Width="40%">
         <span class="zeb">Name:</span>
      </Td>
      <Td Width="60%"><input Type="Text" Style="Width:100%" /></Td>
   </Tr>
   <Tr>
      <Td Class="v11" Width="40%">
         <span class="zah">Email:</span>
      </Td>
      <Td Width="60%"><input Type="Text" Style="Width:100%" /></Td>
   </Tr>
   <Tr>
      <Td Class="v11" Width="40%">
         <span class="zah">Phone:</span>
      </Td>
      <Td Width="60%"><Select Style="Width:100%"></Select></Td>
   </Tr>
</Table>
```

Now you can apply your CSS to all elements with **class** zeb and zah:

```
@media screen and min-width 1px and max-width 460px {
    .zeb, .zah, input.text
    {
        font-size:12px;
    }
}

@media screen and min-width 461px and max-width 770px {
    input.text
    {
        font-size:12px;
    }

    .zeb, .zah
    {
        font-size:16px;
    }
}

@media screen and min-width 771px and max-width 1920px {
    input
    {
        font-size:12px;
    }

    .zeb, .zah
    {
        font-size:22px;
    }
}
```

Notice that I have condensed identical rules by separating selectors with commas.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your response, however, this does not entirely address my issue, and I can not get it to work. I first got a "Conditional compilation turned off" warning, fixed that by adding two () but then it gave me an Invalid Character warning. I realize now why my thing works only once - obviously, I change the class and so the next time can not apply the new class to anything. Dumbbb... but, does jquery allow me to make my own tags, so not <Div> but like <titleitem> or something similar? To which I could then apply an improved/working version of the above? Thanks :)

Comment: @Irresistance If you use this, you do not require the other jQuery stuff to change classes. By the way, it is important to realise this is CSS, not jQuery. I hope you aren't trying to put it in your JS code.

Comment: Right'oh. This just goes to show how ignorant I am on the current 21st century coding. You're talkin' to a guy that has been coding since 1995 on normal HTML with JavaScript... this jQuery stuff is all very new to me, and it is SO simple that it actually catches me off guard. Looks like I really need to spend a week or so to get the hang of it :) Many thanks!

Comment: @Irresistance No probs! Took me a while to get the hang of it, and I'm a pretty new kid on the block. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Yes I most certainly did. AND I can even use my own tags! So that is fabulous. The only thing I cant seem to get work is applying the same change to form (text and select) fields.

Doing this:

@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 460px){
zeb{font-size:12px}
zah{font-size:12px}
input.text{font-size:12px}
}

but both with and without .text it does not work. The others work perfectly

Comment: @Irresistance If you edit your new CSS into the question I could have a look.

Comment: @Irresistance What are `zeb` and `zah`? If they are IDs, they need to be preceded with `#`.

Comment: I have added it to the original post (also need to get the hang of this posting system, very elaborate) :D

Comment: @Irresistance Currently, you are applying those styles to `zeb` elements and `zah` elements. Of course, there are no zeb or zah elements in HTML. Are zeb or zah the classnames or ids for some elements?

Comment: I have added the actual HTML that I want to affect :) Thx :)

Comment: Yay! Victory! Thank You :) Needed to put () around the min and max width, but that aside works like a treat. Also removed all "input" stuff since I can give inputs the proper class now. Awesome :)